# Check the existence of child-object property if parent-object property is empty

Tags: arrays, object, properties, key

```
objectx{propA: valueA,
        propB: valueB,
        propC: [{name: john,  id:123},
                {name: tom, id:456}]
       }
```

1. How to check the existence of `id: 789` in `objectx.propC` ?
2. How to check the existence of `id: 789` in `objectx.propC` if  `objectx.propC` is empty ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
objectx = {propA: 'valueA',
    propB: 'valueB',
    propC: [{name: 'john',  id:123},
            {name: 'tom', id:456}]
   }
function getIdInPropC(objectx,id) {
for (key in objectx.propC) {
    var obj = objectx.propC[key];
    if (!obj) {continue;}
    if (obj.id && obj.id == id) {return obj;}
}
    return false;
}
getIdInPropC(objectx, 456);//returns obj containing top and id 456
getIdInPropC(objectx, 777);//returns false
```